# What is the status of offspring born from same gotra marriage?

Tags: mahabharata, caste-system, manu-smriti

Same gotra marriage is censured . But if such marriage happens , what is the status of the offspring born from such a marriage ?

Comment: They don't loose caste but it's censured to maintain generic purity. The gotra of Father and pind (blood family) of mother should not be taken for marriage, says manu. In some places of southern India and kashmiri Hindus, pind of mother side was allowed but for exceptional circumstances. Gotra of Father is universally forbidden though.